# Inline actions doesn`t show up in Jungle Testnet Monitor

Tags: testnet, inline-action

On the Jungle testnet when I transfer tokens to somebody I can see the transaction in account history, but when I call contract action, which has inline transfer action, I can`t see it on Testnet Monitor.
Can somebody explain why this is happening?